# Naming splitted files incrementally in nifi for a particular table and then reset for another table

Tags: split, apache-nifi

I am doing the following stuff in nifi :
Fetching data from tables in hive and then routing the flow files based on size :
If flowfile size is gt 2GB then split the flow file to multiple flow files of 2Gb each.
I want to use update attribute to name those splits like TableName_001_001,Tablename_001_002,Tablename_001_003 for a particular flow file or table .

When next flow file comes in the split it should also be named like above .

Is there any way we can do with the existing processor ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any other processors **Except SplitRecord** processor for splitting the flowfile into smaller chunks then
each flowfile will have **fragment.index** attribute associated with the flowfile.

As you are having table name as attribute to the flowfile and Make use of these **attributes (table_name and fragment.index)** and combine them to one to **Create the new required attribute** 
 [image]

I'm assuming the tab_name is the table name attribute and Add new property in update attribute processor and

In addition if you want to keep this attributes unique then you can add the timestamp value at the end like

**new_attribute**

```
${tab_name}_${fragment.index}_${now():toNumber()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Route the hive data file based on size to further split on some threshold like 1GB(RouteOnAttribute Processor)

Add Property splits : ${fileSize:gt(size in bytes)}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39qYV.png)

> Name the files based on fragment.index attribute added after the splitText Processor

Go to advanced section of UpdateAttribute Processor and add rules

Add rules and action based on your use case . I have to update the filename so I have used filename Attribute and have added the ${fragment.index} to the filename suffix . If the index is less than 10 then I need 00{fragment.index} , for two digit index value 0{fragment.index} , for rest I wanted {fragment.index} only .

[Adding rules to updateAttribute processor using expression language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4CyY.png)

filename: ${query.input.tables}_001_00${fragment.index}.txt

query.input.tables will give the name of the table fetched from hive . and suffix is added 00${fragment.index}

Like this we can use the power of expression language in Apache Nifi